# Sendmail use java code, can't add body text

Tags: java, sendmail

```
public void sendMailWithPx() {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
                getPathSendMail(),
                "-t"
        });
        String base64File = encodeFileToBase64Binary("/Users/jacye/Downloads/test.pdf");//base64 file
        try (OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream(), "UTF8")) {
            osw.write("Content-Type: application/pdf\n");
            osw.write("From: yourmailtest@testmail.com\n");
            osw.write("To: yourmailtest@testmail.com\n");
            osw.write("Subject: Test send mmail\n");
            osw.write("CC: yourmailtest@testmail.com\n");
            osw.write("BCC: yourmailtest@testmail.com\n");
            osw.write("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf");
            osw.write("\n");
            osw.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64");
            osw.write("\n");
            osw.write(base64File);
            osw.write("this is body");
        }
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        log.error(null, e);
    }
}

private String getPathSendMail() throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try (InputStream input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_FILE)) {
        prop.load(input);
        return prop.getProperty("sendmail.path");
    }
}
```

I send mail with attachment and body text but I don't the receive body text.

How can I send mail with the body text and attachment ?

Comment: why would you not use javamail?

Comment: security for my customer .. can u help me.

Comment: does this work from the command line itself?

Comment: receive attach file not body text ...

Comment: There is no added 'security for your customer' in using `sendmail` rather than JavaMail. Rather to the contrary. NB The line terminator should be `\r\n`, not just `\n`.

Comment: if u use JavaMail u must configure your email and pass, my customer dont want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to send a mail that has a body and an attachment then you have to send it as [MIME Message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046).
The message you are sending just has an attachment (PDF).
I think you can find the "this is body" text as part of the PDF, even it may not get rendered by the PDF Viewers.

A simple [MIME Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms526560(v=exchg.10).aspx) looks the the following way

> From: John Doe example@example.com 
> MIME-Version: 1.0 
> Content-Type:
> multipart/mixed;
> boundary="XXXXboundary text"
>
> This is a multipart message in MIME format.
>
> --XXXXboundary text  Content-Type: text/plain
>
> this is the body text
>
> --XXXXboundary text  Content-Type: text/plain; Content-Disposition: attachment;
> filename="test.txt"
>
> this is the attachment text
>
> --XXXXboundary text--